# Django - custom sessions with REST login support

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-sessions

We need to implement Django app with custom sessions.
What we need:
- login is being done via REST
- Django is only wrapper for REST services

Can I use some king of custom sessions in django which will support login via REST? (lats assume I will send login and password via rest)

Could you suggest any built-in solution or 3rd party lib for such use case?

Comment: I've forgot to mension: API will served from different than python/django technology. We need to implement client, which will consume that API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need any kind of custom session in django and any 3rd party lib either. Django session app doesn't have strong (sql-)relations with other django-applications(auth in your case). If you want to do login via your REST-service, just write your login function and put result in session. Something like this:

```
def login(login, pass):
  return urllib.urlget('https://mysite.io/login?user=%s&pass=%s'%(login, pass))

def my_veiew(request):
  if request.method=='POST':
    request.session['user']=login(request.POST['user'], request.POST['pass'])
    return HttpResponseRedirrect('somewhere')
  return TemplateResponse(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```

Note that you can put any type of python object in your session, for example your own wrapper class. This is why I like django session so much! =)

You can find more information about django session [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/) and choose which type of session backend fit for your project.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [built-in authentication classes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication) in Django REST framework, and also the [third party packages](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#third-party-packages).  One of those might be what you're looking for.

Comment: It may be useful for API server not client (what we need).